# How to Install python-telegram-bot version 20 and above

Tags: python, pip, telegram

Trying to run examples or telegram bots from official site - https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/master/examples
Installed :

```
pip install python-telegram-bot
```

and when i run the example, i got error back that version is not compatible.

```
if __version_info__ < (20, 0, 0, "alpha", 1):
    raise RuntimeError(
        f"This example is not compatible with your current PTB version {TG_VER}. To view the "
        f"{TG_VER} version of this example, "
        f"visit https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/v{TG_VER}/examples"
    )
```

It installs PyPi version 13.12 but example checks different version v20. So, the error is reasonable.
How can I let example working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shame on me, I spent a couple of days to get the answer - 20x is pre-release version only! To find clear explanation, you have to read WiKi and not even on the first page - https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/introduction-to-the-API
That was the only source of info with clear answer with 20x status and right installation procedure.
So, here is the procedure - `pip install python-telegram-bot -U --pre`
btw, you have to check if "telegram" package installed also. Uninstall it first and then reinstall telegram-bot from the scratch (better with force option).

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are using examples from `v20.0` version, change the tag to `v13.12`
[image]

Comment: Yes, @SpazaM, you are right. it is 20.x examples. after a few days I realized that 20.x is not released yet. The only place to find the answer on the site - https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/introduction-to-the-API 
All other sources give no clear information about the status and the way to install the package.

Comment: :), if it really helped you, I will be glad if you can accept this answer.